# Node.js script stops without any error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written a scraper using the `scraper` module and the `queue` function of `async` module.

I read the list of URLs to scrap from a json file and write the informations in another JSON file.

This is my script:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var scrap = require("scrap"),
    async = require("async");

var errors = [];

// Queue a list of URLs
var queue = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("products.json", "utf8"));
var len = queue.products.length;

var q = async.queue(function (url, done) {

    scrap(url, function(err, $) {
        var product = {};
        product.name = $("#page-body h2").first().text().trim();
        product.myarr = [];
        product.picture = $(".content img").first().attr("src");

        try {
            if (product.picture.indexOf("someword") > 1) {
                delete product.picture;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }

        $(".content [style^=\"color: #\"] [style=\"font-weight: bold\"], .content [style=\"font-weight: bold\"] [style^=\"color: #\"]").each(function() {
            product.myarr.push($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase());
        });

        if (product.myarr.length) {
            fs.appendFile("products-parsed.json", JSON.stringify(product) + ",\n", function (err) {
                console.log(queue.products.indexOf(url), len, err);
                if (err) { errors.push(queue.products.indexOf(url)); }
                done();
            });
        }
    });

}, 20);

q.drain = function() {
    console.log(errors);
};

q.push(queue.products);
```

When I run it, after about 3.000 pages, it stops (quit) and it does not give any error, I have to start from the latest worked page using:

```
q.push(queue.products.slice(lastWorkedPage, queue.products.length - 1));
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: dude how are you running node in codepen ?

Comment: I've just used codepen to share the code..

Comment: then better to paste here,codepen seems you'll be giving a demo.

Comment: I thought was too long to post there.

Comment: Can be that you got overflow error. If products will be a quite big, then storing all of this data in ```q``` can make RAM overlow.

Comment: so how can I fix it? I've ran an older version of this script successfully in past with the same amount of pages..

Comment: Write more optimized code :) It's a long story how fix this. Process products by parts, remove already processed data, etc.

Comment: I've tried splitting products in parts and create a new queue after each chunk but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, by the way seems like the problem was caused by this row:

```
console.log(queue.products.indexOf(url), len, err);
```

Commenting it has solved the problem, feel free to give a more accurate answer which explains the solution and I'll set it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet so I have to post new answer.

I can confirm console.log - error. NodeJS/Express sometimes just stops when trying to use console.log()!

Code from one test-project:

```
        console.log(req.body.credentials.password, isMatch);
        if (isMatch) {
            sess.currentUser = user;
            console.log(user);
            res.send({ status: "ok", loginUser: user });
        }
        else {
            res.send({ status : "error", msg: "Login failed!" });
        }
```

Second logging line (console.log(user)) stops NodeJS without error! And that happens only in some environments - in most dev environments this works just fine!